# How to do max to date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I try to get the max of `last_modify_date` column of each row by name.

I get only one result, but I want to get something like this result:

```
name | v | last_modify_date
---------------------------
example1 | 100 | 2024-01-03 12:00:00
example2 | 100 | ...
example3 | 100 | ...
```

The query:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
(
    name VARCHAR(50),
    value INT,
    last_modify_date DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO MyTable (name, value, last_modify_date) 
VALUES ('Example1', 100, '2024-01-01 12:00:00'),
       ('Example1', 100, '2024-01-02 12:00:00'),
       ('Example1', 100, '2024-01-03 12:00:00'),
       ('Example2', 100, '2024-01-02 12:00:00'),
       ('Example2', 100, '2024-01-02 18:00:00'),
       ('Example3', 100, '2024-01-02 12:00:00');

SELECT name, [value] as v, MAX(last_modify_date) 
FROM MyTable;
```

PS: if it possible to NOT using group by because in my original query I select 30 columns and I don't want to duplicate those columns in group by.

Comment: you can use Window functiosn, but as SELECT * are bad style, so you should write all wanted rows out

Comment: `select distinct ..., max(last_modify_date) over (partition by name)` Something about this whole query feels wrong though.

Comment: You can also do a scalar, correlated subquery: `select A, B, C, (select max(last_modify_date) from T t2 where t2.name = t.name) as D from ...`

Comment: Can you use json in your db?

Answer (score 2):

The below works for me but please note that this table is not good design in terms of relational data and this worked with the sample data provided and I'm not sure you will be able to avoid duplicates in your actual data. Also try and avoid naming columns with sql keywords like "value" and "name"

```
SELECT name, [value] as v, max(last_modify_date) FROM 
MyTable
group by name, value
```

Data :

[image]

Result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function for the same

```
select name,value as v, max(last_modify_date) over(partition by name) from MyTable
```

[answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9B0R.png)

Answer (score -2):

Of course, you could do the group by as above, and then join that result back to the original table on the primary key. (no idea what it is, though).